# Foundation mobile menu won't appear on small screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

My head is about to explode. I can't get the mobile 'hamburger' menu to appear for small screens. The word "Menu" is visible, but the icon doesn't toggle.

It's probably something very obvious but I've been looking at this for too long and can't see the vault. Anyone able to help?

Am I calling the right JS?

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>Website Title</title>
<!--Favicon-->
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon">
<!--Fonts-->
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:600, 400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<!--CSS-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
<!--FOUNDATION JS-->
<script src="js/foundation/foundation.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation/foundation.topbar.js"></script>
```

and here's my nav section

```
<div class="topbar">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-4 columns">
      <a href="#home"><h1 class="logo">Website Name</h1></a>
    </div>
    <div class="large-8 text-right columns">
    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="large-12 columns">
        <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation">
        <ul class="right button-group title-area">
        <li><a href="#home" class="button nav">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about" class="button nav">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#office" class="button nav">Examples</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact" class="button nav navlast">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>MENU</span></a></li>
        </ul>
        </nav>
       </div>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: don't add improvements to your code after posting. The answer from mrseo88 now does not make sense and risks being downvoted by others.

Comment: @mousey Will amend and restore original code.

Comment: I don't see any responsive css

Answer (score 0):

You missed some foundation js includs and functions, try like this:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>Website Title</title>
<!--Favicon-->
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon">
<!--Fonts-->
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:600, 400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<!--CSS-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
<!--FOUNDATION JS-->
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).foundation();
</script>
```

Comment: appreciate the answer. Sadly it didn't work. Still not switching to mobile menu when I switch to small screen

Answer (score 0):

Having top-bar contained in such a small container will cause the menu items to not have room. Also calling the top-bar.js file imported before jquery wont work since jquery is a dependancy.

You actually don't need to call it again since foundation.min.js has all the plugins.

I added more details here: http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/34724-foundation-mobile-menu-wont-appear-on-small-screen